# Projective subvarieties are closed?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

I want to show that projective subvarieties of a quasi-projective variety are closed. One possible solution should be the following:

Let $W \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ be a quasi-projective variety and $V \subseteq W$ a projective subvariety. Then the natural inclusion $\iota: V \hookrightarrow W$ is a regular map. Since $V$ is projective, the image $V = \iota(V) \subseteq W$ is closed by the closed map theorem.

My question is: is there a more elementary and more direct way of proving this theorem, e.g. using only the definitions of projective varieties and closed?

I wanted to use this for proving that $\mathbb{P}^n \setminus \{x\}$ is not projective (since $\mathbb{P}^n \setminus \{x\} \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ is not closed).

Comment: Projective subvarieties are compact, and compact things are closed. Though you did not specify the topology, which one do you want?

Comment: @MishaVerbitsky $k$ an arbitrary (algebraically closed) field and $\mathbb{P}^n = \mathbb{P}^n(k)$ with the Zariski topology. Then this doesn't work since all quasi-projective varieties are compact but as the Zariski topology is not Hausdorff this does not imply closedness. Although the projective case is probably analog to the compact case for manifolds.

Comment: Then it follows from the valuative criterion of properness, indeed